# jQuery Live Regexp Check

Tags: jquery, regex

So, I have an input box with default value as "www.mysite.com/users/", here after this values users should be able to define a short URL for themselves, for example: "mike".

Now, I want to only allow a-z and A-Z for the short URL, I want to check the user input live and prevent them to use other characters as &%!"£..., here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="short_url" value="www.mysite.com/users/" />
<script>
    ('#short_url').on('keypress', function(){
                var short_url = $(this).val();
                if(short_url.substr(0, 21) != 'www.mysite.com/users/'){
                    $(this).val('www.mysite.com/users/');
                }else{
                    // Only allow a-z
                        short_url = short_url.substr(21);
                        var RegEx = /^[a-z0-9]$/;
                        if(!RegEx.test(short_url)) {
                            if(short_url != '')
                            return false;
                        }
                }
            });
</script>
```

What I tried in the above code is that not let the user to clear my site.com, so he had to add his short URL after the default value, and also only allow the RegEx to be typed, but it's not working. how should I implement this?

Another thing is that, I also want to allow dot in the short URL, but just 1 dot!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe just use one regex: /www.mysite.com\/users\/[a-z0-9]/i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your base URL will never change... why not just make that static text before your input field. It will drastically simplify your code.

```
<span>www.mysite.com/users/</span>
<input id="short_url" type="text" />​
```

And then a little jQuery to handle the validation

```
(function(){

    var shortUrlRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z]*(\.{1}[a-zA-Z]*)?$/;

    $("#short_url").on("keyup", function(){

        var text = $(this).val();

        var isMatch = shortUrlRegexp.test(text);

        $(this).toggleClass("invalid", !isMatch);

    });

}());​
```

Here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/PP7HP/).

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this is not what I wanted at all! I want that base url in my input and also not allow the user to "type" anything but characters with jQuery keypress(), thanks anyway

Comment: @behz4d - My question is why do you **need** to have that base url in the input if it never changes? I can certainly update the example, but you should be able to adapt it to fit your needs.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm using this way, but this RegEx seems to allow dot in the beginning/end of text, how I should only allow it between the text, not as first or last character

Comment: @behz4d - you just need to change the '*' to be a '+' instead. That means **At least one character to infinity**

Answer (score 0):

This will allow alpha-numeric + one `.`. Must start and end with an alpha-numeric char

```
^[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z0-9]+$
```